# ArcGIS map service not resizing for print-friendly page

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, dojo

( I asked this **[same question on ArcGIS forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/89553-map-object-not-resized-using-print.css)**, with no response...I hope someone here can help!)

I am using ArcView, ArcServer 10.0 and the JS API v3.1 (so no print function) ... I have an app where the user chooses parameters from a few dropdown menus, and a print-friendly map page opens in a new tab. From this page, the user can click a 'print' button, which uses window.print() to open the browser's print dialog. I have a print.css page, which is working well with my 'normal' divs, text and images. I have this tag in my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to reset the size of the Dojo map object. The map in my printed page (or PDF, if I choose CutePDF) is the same size as whatever the size was in the print-friendly page. I would like my print.css to hard define the printed version / PDF as an exact height and width, regardless of the window size in the print-friendly page. I cannot define the size of page to be printed in the print-friendly page, b/c for one, my client would like to pan and zoom the map after the print-friendly page is generated. I have no problem setting the size of the other elements in my print.css rules (text box, hard coded legend with images)...but any rules I try to set for the map itself in my print.css page are ignored.

I tried using 'exportMapImage', thinking that maybe I could make an image of the map and its contents, but this loses the basemap which I need, and also I do not want the user to open yet another page or tab. (I am having the same problem with my scalebar, but I this isn't so important for this project).

My goal is to create a PDF or printed page that is the same size no matter what the screen size or current window size., and I have it working except for the map itself.

Any ideas? I hope I explained my problem clearly. Thanks , J

Also,  I am hoping to find a client-side solution; I don't have much experience with server-side programming.  If this can't happen, please let me know any server-side ideas, thanks!)

Comment: Upgrading to ArcGIS 10.1 (or 10.2) may or may not be an option for you but, if you are not aware of it, that version addressed [**Advanced printing for web maps**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Advanced_printing_for_web_maps/01540000056t000000/).

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to your ArcGIS Discussion Forum posting?  That way anyone looking to answer can benefit from any advice offered there before covering the same ground.

Comment: yes, here it is: [link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/89553-map-object-not-resized-using-print.css)...sorry I should have added that right away. As far as ArcServer 10.1, sadly I don't think we will be getting this anytime soon, so I am stuck with 10.0.  I am aware of the new print functionality, but I can't use it.  This has been a bit frustrating for me, as hard-coding the css for the other div elements to make a print-friendly page is quite easy.

Comment: I realized that one issue here was that I was tryong to display a landscape oriented print view, which was cauing problems in IE. The 'Shrink To Fit' option always tried to frame the page in portrait mode.  I have read that this is a known issue on IE 9 and below.